# ERROR: Error: Request timed out - InfluxDB sitespeed.io

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile, influxdb

I have a problem saving data in an influxdb database, for information I use a docker machine that contains InfluxDb + Grafana, I do not know where it comes from this error?

[Screenshot Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzvNo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try create docker network and run sitespeed in this network:

```
docker network create influxdb
docker run -p 8086:8086  -d --name=influxdb --net=influxdb influxdb
docker run --shm-size=1g --rm -v "$(pwd)":/sitespeed.io --net=influxdb sitespeedio/sitespeed.io https://www.sitespeed.io  --influxdb.host=influxdb --influxdb.username=admin --influxdb.password=admin
```